# Template binding in angular 4

Tags: angular

Below is my partial component code

```
....

....
ngOnInit() 
{

this.service.getData().subscribe( function(data) {

    try 
    {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // {"name":"john"}
      this.ajaxdata = data;
}
catch(err) 
{
   console.log('Error Here....');
}

        });
}
....
....
```

and below is my partial template related code

```
{{ ajaxdata?.name }}
```

console.log statement in the above code prints  "{"name":"john"}" as expected.
But {{ ajaxdata?.name }} does not print "john" , any idea what could be the reason ?

Comment: why is there `?` after `ajaxdata`?

Comment: can you give your services code ?

Comment: @AgamBanga https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: Ahhh! Didn't know that in angular2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have lost the context of `this`.

In your code, `this` is currently not pointing to your class instance of `ajaxdata`. There are a couple of ways to fix this. The easiest of which I believe is to use an arrow function as below:

```
this.service.getData()
  .subscribe(data => this.ajaxdata = data)
```

More information on this can be [**found here**](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript)

Answer (score 2):

You have lost `this` context.

Solutions are attached below:

**Way 1:**

```
this.service.getData().subscribe( function(data) {
    try {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // {"name":"john"}
        this.ajaxdata = data;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('Error Here....');
    }

}.bind(this))
```

**Way 2:**

```
this.service.getData().subscribe( (data) => {
        try {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // {"name":"john"}
            this.ajaxdata = data;
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log('Error Here....');
        }

    })
```

It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

```
{{ajaxdata.?name }}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator